# How to Set my Mac $PATH back the way it was before in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I’m just getting started with “Terminal,” the other day I might have messed something up with my `/usr/local/bin`. When executing `echo $PATH` it returns me with:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The original path was:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

How do I set it back to factory settings?

Comment: I think you are mistaken about what `$PATH` used to have, my path is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`, and I am pretty sure the only added directory is the `/opt/X11/bin`. If you look inside `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, /sbin` I think you find some pretty important commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the `$PATH` var in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` depends on whatever shell you use.

Comment: But how should the OP edit it? The OP is clearly wrong stating that the original `$PATH` was `/usr/local/bin`. Also, OS X Terminal starts a login shell, so `.bashrc` isn't read.

Answer (score 0):

The original `$PATH` on OS X is certainly not just `/usr/local/bin`.

I am guessing you changed your `.bash_profile` to modify the path. So, if you are still able to run commands, run:

```
/usr/bin/open -e ~/.bash_profile
```

Here, remove all the statements you added that have to do with setting `PATH`. Save the file. Restart the Terminal.

If you did not modify anything else (e.g. messed around with `/etc/profile`), that should do it.